# JSON::ParserError 757: unexpected token Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, import, gateway

Hi there I am trying to import messages from an external gateway into my database in Ruby on Rails, the the messages are sent using JSON, but whatever I tey I keep getting and error:

```
757: unexpected token at 'sting another 8:16 09\/02\/2013","from":"254720321222","to":"2658","date":"2013-02-09 17:17:19"},{"id":256069,"text":"Wajpt","from":"254704476069","to":"2658","date":"2013-02-09 20:12:30"},{"id":256510,"text":"STOP","from":"254789934061","to":"2658","date":"2013-02-10 07:20:01"},{"id":256774,"text":"Adan","from":"254729933301","to":"2658","date":"2013-02-10 10:36:11"},{"id":257039,"text":"1967","from":"254700365399","to":"2658","date":"2013-02-10 14:13:55"}]}}
```

This is my Controller code:

```
    require 'AfricasTalkingGateway'

class MessageController < ApplicationController
    username = 'username'
    apikey   = 'apikey'

    gateway  = AfricasTalkingGateway.new(username, apikey)

    last_received_id = 212815
    while true
      messages = gateway.fetch_messages(last_received_id)

      messages.each {|x|
        puts 'from' + x.from + 'to' + x.to + 'text' + x.text + 'date' + x.date
        last_received_id = x.id
      }

      break if messages.length == 0

    def create
    @message = Message.new(:from => x.from, :to => x.to, :date => x.date, :text => x.text, :giud => x.id)
    @message.save

  def index
    @message = Message.find(:all)
  end
end
```

and my gateway rb file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'curb'
require 'json'

class AfricasTalkingGatewayAuthenticationError < Exception
end

class AfricasTalkingGatewayUnexpectedError < Exception
end

class SMSMessage
  attr_accessor :id, :text, :from, :to, :date

  def initialize(m_id, m_text,m_from, m_to ,m_date)
    @id = m_id
    @text = m_text
    @from = m_from
    @to = m_to
    @date = m_date
  end
end


class StatusReport
  attr_accessor :number, :status, :cost

  def initialize(m_number, m_status, m_cost)
    @number = m_number
    @status = m_status
    @cost = m_cost
  end
end

class AfricasTalkingGateway

  #Constants
  URL = 'https://api.africastalking.com/version1/messaging'
  ACCEPT_TYPE = 'application/json'

  def initialize(user_name,api_key)
    @user_name = user_name
    @api_key = api_key
  end

  def send_message(recipients, message)
    data = nil
    response_code = nil

    post_body = {:username => @user_name, :message => message, :to => recipients }

    http = Curl.post(URL, post_body) do |curl|
      curl.headers['Accept'] = ACCEPT_TYPE
      curl.headers['apiKey'] = @api_key
      curl.verbose = true

      curl.on_body { |body|
        data = body
        body.to_s.length
      }
      curl.on_complete { |resp| response_code = resp.response_code }
    end

    raise AfricasTalkingGatewayAuthenticationError if response_code == 401
    raise AfricasTalkingGatewayUnexpectedError "Unexpected error occured" if response_code != 201 or data.nil?

    reports = JSON.parse(data)["SMSMessageData"]["Recipients"].collect { |entry|
      StatusReport.new entry["number"], entry["status"], entry["cost"]
    }
    return reports

  end

  def fetch_messages(last_received_id)
    data = nil
    response_code = nil

    http = Curl.get("#{URL}?username=#{@user_name}&lastReceivedId=#{last_received_id}") do |curl|
      curl.headers['Accept'] = ACCEPT_TYPE
      curl.headers['apiKey'] = @api_key
      curl.verbose = false
      curl.on_body { |body|
        data = body
        body.to_s.length
      }
      curl.on_complete { |resp| response_code = resp.response_code }
    end

    raise AfricasTalkingGatewayAuthenticationError if response_code == 401
    raise AfricasTalkingGatewayUnexpectedError "Data is nil for some unexpected reason" if response_code != 200 or data.nil?

    messages = JSON.parse(data)["SMSMessageData"]["Messages"].collect { |msg|
      SMSMessage.new msg["id"], msg["text"], msg["from"] , msg["to"], msg["date"]

    }    


    return messages

  end
end
```

Please help me solve this issue

Comment: Without seeing the actual JSON document in its entirety we cannot help you. Try posting it to some online JSON parser(http://json.parser.online.fr/) and see if it gets parsed correctly. If not - your gateway gives away badly formatted documents and there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: I tried 
`757: unexpected token at '14:09:50"},{"id":216858,"text":"STOP","from":"254735295406","to":"2658","date":"2013-01-27 17:05:59"},{"id":218014,"text":"I'm busy now,call you later.","from":"254701512352","to":"2658","date":"2013-01-28 12:39:35"},{"id":218392,"text":"DB87FO581 confirmed. You bought Ksh10.00 of airtime for 0721398988 on 27\/1\/13 at 8:23 AM New M-PESA balance is Ks","from":"254712418641","to":"2658","date":"2013-01-28 15:40:07"},{"id":226572,"text":"I'm busy now,call you later.","from":"254701512352","to":"2658","date":"2013-01-30 07:00:08"}]}}'`